# Moving from using innerHTML for an AJAX response. (Code is not getting a response)

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

I am currently using the code as seen below but it is insecure and can be used to exploit the website using XSS.

Old Code, that works:

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xmlHTTP.responseText;
```

New code that is giving no response:

```
var divContent = xmlHTTP.responseText;            
  var getRes = document.getElementById('response');
  if (getRes.innerText) {
      getRes.innerText = divContent; //For Safari, Google Chrome and MSIE.
  }
  else
  if (getRes.textContent) {
      getRes.textContent = divContent; //For Firefox.
    }   
}
```

The basic HTML Div below:

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

Furthermore the output is HTML, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div is empty. If `innerText` or `textContent` are defined, then they will be empty strings. Empty strings are not true values.

Create text nodes instead, they are standard and well supported.

```
document.getElementById('response').appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(
        xmlHTTP.responseText
    )
);
```

If you need to empty the element first you can always:

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: This is nearly there but the output is HTML.